# HTTPS redirect from non www to non www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a non-WWW domain and when I try to set up redirect to HTTPS, redirect from http://www.examle.com to https://www.example.com works for me, but http://example.com does not work on https://example.com. The current htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*index\.html/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html/?$ https://$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !index\.php 
RewriteCond $1 !^assets
RewriteCond $1 !^robots.txt
RewriteCond $1 !^sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Can you advise what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*index\.html/?$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html/?$ https://$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond $1 !index\.php 
RewriteCond $1 !^assets 
RewriteCond $1 !^robots.txt 
RewriteCond $1 !^sitemap.xml 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this rule for `https` redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This has first condition as `%{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.` which means it will only match host names starting with `www.` thus you will not get redirect for `http://example.com/`.

You may use this redirect rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This will perform following redirects:

1. `http://example.com/ => https://example.com/`
2. `http://www.example.com/ => https://www.example.com/`

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: No, still the same problem. :(

Comment: Moreover make to keep my suggested rule as your **topmost** rule just below `RewriteEngine` line and clear your browser cache.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the original post. Still does not work.

Comment: What is your Apache version and may I know your actual domain name for testing?

Comment: Version Apache / 2.4.25 (Debian) and website is https://smajlici.info/

Comment: I did a curl to `http://smajlici.info` and `http://smajlici.info` but both didn't redirect at all. btw you have`Server: openresty/1.13.6.2`

Comment: Yes, it is a problem that there is no redirection of http://smajlici.info to https://smajlici.info, but from http://www.smajlici.info to https://smajlici.info it works. I don't know what openresty is.

Comment: You have some hosting issue as `www.smajlici.info` doesn't resolve

Comment: So I'll ask the hosting company. Thank you very much